# Highlight the Recyclerview touched item after finishing and recreating activity

Tags: android

I'm loading some images into recyclerview and highlighted the image touched by user .It's working good but whenever the activity getting finished in my onDestroy() and again creating the activity,i'm losing the highlight on the item.
Please help me how to restore the  highlight in the adapter of recyclerview.

Comment: Don't ask plain questions. Provide related code. That may give better clarity. And you can get the solution soon.

Comment: You can set 'isHighLighted' variable in your model which is used to generate recyclerview (RecyclerView Items). Whenever user touched the image change this variable to true. And In your Adapter use this(isHighlighted) variable to highlight the item. This data is associated with the model so you will not lose the data when the activity is recreated.